# List of math and logic operations - shorten the program code

Tags: c

I have three variables: a, b, c. I would like the program to display the results of six math and logic operations on these variables.
List of operations: +, -, *, &, |, ^,
For example:

```
a + b + c;
a + b - c;
a + b * c;
a + b & c;
a + b | c;
a + b ^ c;
a - b + c;
a - b - c:
a - b * c;
```

e.t.c.

Is there any other way to shorten the program code instead of writing all possible combinations of operations on three variables line by line?
For example, is it possible to put operators in an array and replace them in a loop?

```
oper_tab [6] = {'+', '-', '*', '&', '|', '^'}; // ????????
```

Or maybe there is another way?
I will be grateful for any comments.

Comment: In C you cannot create a calculation like `a + b * c` based on a loop over an array of operator characters or operator enums. You would probably have to use `switch`/`case` to interpret the operator characters and implement the operator precedence.

Comment: also needs details and more focus because its not clear what code should be shortened (where is thecode?) and becaue you seem to have a solution but it isnt clear what is the issue with that. Yes you can use an array with each operator stored as character and yes there are also other ways. Did you try anything?

Comment: https://ideone.com/lcXk10

Comment: I can guess what the original code looks like, but better post it. If I guessed incorrectly, my answer would not be useful.

Comment: LOL @user904963, exactly right... operator precedence is too large to fit in a comment :-)

Comment: What's with these votes to close to focus the question? All that was needed was an edit to the tags, and the question is perfectly clear. He wants to have a list of operators and output the result of a op1 b op2 c for all combinations of (op1, op2). The code to shorten is enumerating all possible combinations like his example code shows.

Comment: You cannot do this in runtime, because then the source code is no more changeable, and C is commonly a compiled language, not an interpreted one. However, you might consider to write a script or program that _generates_ the full source for you.

Comment: Here is a version with precedence based on the code from @pmg https://ideone.com/ZYyeXt

Comment: Ok. understood. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You solve pretty much every problem in C by throwing enough ugly macros at it :)

In this case it would be possible to use and [X-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) list. Here is an example with 2 operands.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// X macro list of operators supported:
#define OP_LIST(X) \
  X(+) \
  X(-) \
  X(*) \
  X(&) \
  X(|) \
  X(^) \

int main(void)
{
  int a=1;
  int b=2;

  #define EXEC(op) printf("%d %s %d = %d\n", a, #op, b, (a op b));
  OP_LIST(EXEC)

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 = 3
1 - 2 = -1
1 * 2 = 2
1 & 2 = 0
1 | 2 = 3
1 ^ 2 = 3
```

Since you haven't really demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem yourself, expanding this code to use 3 operands instead is purposely left as an exercise to the reader :)

Hint: you can count the number of operators in the X macro list using stringinizing macro tricks and a compound literal:

```
#define STRINGINIZE(op) #op
#define COUNT_OPS(op) STRINGINIZE(op),
const size_t OP_N = sizeof (char*[]){ OP_LIST(COUNT_OPS) } / sizeof(char*);
// OP_N is now 6 for the above specified OP_LIST
```

Comment: That is very useful too. Thank you Lundin !

Comment: `#define EXEC(op) printf("%d %s %d %s %d = %d\n", a, #op, b, #op, c, (a op b op c));`   ???

Comment: @th3r4t3l I think you need to invent a way to iterate over operators in a "binary fashion". That is `+ +`, `+ -`, ... , `- +`, `- -` and so on, cover all combinations. In order to do so you'll probably need to know the amount of operators supported, which can be obtained from the size macro I posted at the bottom of the answer.